# Check for logged in user with the Element API plugin

Tags: plugin-elementapi

Working on a SPA with Vue and Craft and looking to check if a user is logged in to run some Vue conditional logic.

I imagine that will then enable me to check if the logged in user owns content to return as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to do this from your transformer, then something like this should work:

```
'transformer' => function($entry) {

    $isLoggedIn = craft()->userSession->isLoggedIn(); 

    if ($isLoggedIn) {
        // Do your custom logic.
    }

    return array(
        'title' => $entry->title,
        'url' => $entry->url,
        'description' => (string) $entry->description,
        'photos' => $photos
    );
},
```

Comment: huh - that's easy :)